# How to Configure a tor on a domain-joined Windows at work

Tags: windows, bridge, proxy, log

i can use tor at home with no difficulty,but i need use it at work too.
my PC at work is a domain-joined PC and i have no right to change any thing like firewall. the PC is configured to connect to internet via a proxy server.
i install tor and configured it with all five (obsf4, obsf3,....) transport types but none of them worked!

i tried to use custom bridges s(end get bridges request to bridges@bridges.torproject.org they gave me two bridges and copied them in custom bridges ) but not been able to connect again!!

any idea how can i solve the problem?
can tor be used in a restricted PC with no firewall configuration assess?

by the way here is the log:

- 2017/09/13 15:23:13 ب.ظ.500 [WARN] The https proxy sent back an unexpected status code 502 ("Proxy Error ( The specified Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) port is not allowed. Forefront TMG is not configured to allow SSL requests from this port. Most Web browsers use port 443 for SSL requests.  )"). Closing.
- 2017/09/13 15:23:13 ب.ظ.500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 198.23.251.193:43019
- 2017/09/13 15:38:58 ب.ظ.500 [WARN] The https proxy sent back an unexpected status code 502 ("Proxy Error ( The specified Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) port is not allowed. Forefront TMG is not configured to allow SSL requests from this port. Most Web browsers use port 443 for SSL requests.  )"). Closing.
- 2017/09/13 15:38:58 ب.ظ.500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 194.135.89.229:7182
- 2017/09/13 15:47:41 ب.ظ.500 [WARN] The https proxy sent back an unexpected status code 407 ("Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )"). Closing.
- 2017/09/13 15:47:41 ب.ظ.500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 82.211.2.240:443
- 2017/09/13 16:07:02 ب.ظ.200 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
- 2017/09/13 16:07:02 ب.ظ.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
- 2017/09/13 16:07:02 ب.ظ.200 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to configure proxy credentials to access the internet.

Onion/Tor Button -> Network Settings

Tick '*This computer needs to use a local proxy to access the Internet*' and configure the proxy type, address, port, username and password (all of this information is the same as you would use to access the internet normally).

Comment: I have already set the proxy setting in tor as you mentioned, but no success 

Comment: It may be the case that the proxy wants to use some uncommon authentication mechanism and that's why it's rejecting the credentials. In that case there's not much you can do with Tor itself, you'd need to write some program to translate between a normal HTTP proxy and the upstream proxy, which gets complex and ugly quickly :(

Comment: how am i able to make sure the proxy uses authentication or not?